# How to delete a single data point in grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, datapoint

I'm getting data from two solar inverters via influxdb & grafana. It works fine, but sometimes, due to an unknwon issue, one value of some parameters of one of the inverters is extremely high, way too high for it to make sense. Is there a way to delete a single data point so that it's no longer be shown in the graph?

Example image: [efficiency of both solar inverters can't be higher than 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqiDM.png)

("Wirkungsgrad" is german for efficiency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafana doesn't manage data in the InfluxDB usually (very likely your Grafana has read only access to the InfluxDB, otherwise it won't be very secure). So question if Grafana can delete InfluxDB data point is not very accurate.

You can:

1.) Execute `DELETE` InfluxDB query for that particular data point (as user with proper InfluxDB permissions - I guess only InfluDB admins can do that)

2.) On the Grafana level you can configure `Y-Max`:`100` for your Y axe, so those 100+ values will be out of visible graph area

3.) You can even filter it out in the Grafana InfluxDB query, e.g. `WHERE value <= 100`, so in that case high values won't be event returned by InfluxDB

Comment: Thanks :) Solution 2) I knew of already, sadly the connection to this point stays there even if the point isn't visible. Solution 3 works in this case, so thank you very much for that. Although it would be nice if I could just click the specific point and hit ```del``` on my keyboard...